# VS2010 Intellisense on class files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, asp.net-4.0

I have a Web Application Project that I'm working on.

My solution looks like this :

```
./MyProject/
./MyProject/dataobjects.cs <- no intellisense
./MyProject/sqlquerying.cs <- no intellisense

./MyProject/default.aspx <- intellisense works here
./MyProject/default.aspx.cs <- intellisense works here
./MyProject/mypage.aspx <- intellisense works here
./MyProject/mypage.aspx.cs <- intellisense works here
```

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't give me any intellisense options when I work on non-code-behind files like Business Logic Layers and Data Logic Layers . In VS2008, I placed these files in the App_Code folder and intellisense worked fine.

What can I do?
Is there a specific folder I need to put these files in to get intellisense?

Comment: The solution was created in VS2010 as a Web Application and hasn't been converted to anything different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

Visual Studio was setting my code files as 'Content' instead of 'Compile' for the build option.

Here's an excerpt from the [same question on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/bd76accc-f7b1-4a61-8a88-437e07aeb507/) for anyone who's interested:

> if you're having
>   the intellisense issue, another thing
>   to check is the "Build Action" for
>   your code file... just look at the
>   file's properties and make sure the
>   "Build Action" property is set to
>   "Compile".

Answer (score 2):

You may have a "Website" rather than a "Web Application".

In a Website non-page code files need to be either in App_Code or (ideally) in a separate project that is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You should have intellisense, regardless of where you put your class files. Is this a new VS 2010 project converted from a VS 2008 website?

Try right-clicking the project, and selecting 'Convert to Web Application'.

In a web application, You should have the aspx files, designer files, and code behind files. I have experienced similar oddities when converting a VS 2008 website to VS 2010 web application.